# Cronômetro com tempo errado

Tags: c++, qt, time, timer

Tenho um cronometro feito com QtSDK, porém quando ele é iniciado **o tempo corre absurdamente mais rápido do que o normal**. Segue o código abaixo:

```
QTime time;
QTimer timer;

void PlanejamentoWidget::timeUpdate(){
    QTime t = ui.timeEdit->time();
    ui.timeEdit->setTime(t.addMSecs(time.elapsed()));
}

void PlanejamentoWidget::startTimer(){
    if (timer.isActive()){
       ui.btStart->setText("Iniciar");
       timer.stop();
    }
    else{       
        ui.btStart->setText("Parar");
        time.start();
        timer.start(60);
    }
}

void PlanejamentoWidget::restartTimer(){
    time.restart();
    QTime t;
    t.setHMS(0, 0, 0, 0);
    ui.timeEdit->setTime(t);
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser? Obrigado.

Comment: O que é absurdamente mais rápido? Como você chegou a esta conclusão? Dê mais detalhes, fica difícil entender o problema só com estas informações.

Comment: No contador do cronometro 10 segundos são equivalentes a cerca 5 segundos do tempo real.

Comment: E essa diferença vai aumentando com o passar do tempo do cronometro.

Comment: O método `timeUpdate` é o chamado a cada tick to seu timer? Outra coisa, é mesmo o que você deseja iniciar o timer com o valor `60`? Só lembrando que o valor esperado é em milisegundos...

Comment: Outra coisa: provavelmente você deseja alterar `ui.timeEdit` diretamente com o valor de `time.elapsed()` e não somar o tempo decorrido ao que já estava lá no campo da Interface. Provavelmente esse é o erro.

Comment: Note que QtCreator é apenas uma IDE e não "faz nada" além de organizar o seu projeto, quem compila ele no Windows é o VisualStudio ou o MingW. O termo QT pode ser usado para se referir ao qtSDK (que é uma biblioteca com funções prontas para facilitar o desenvolvimento, principalmente no caso de cross-platform).

Comment: Se diferença vai aumentando é por que o timer está sendo executado mais de uma vez.

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema é que `time.elapsed()` é a quantidade tempo desde que você chamou `time.start()` em milisegundos. Por isso, que a diferença vai aumentando - o valor nunca é zerado.

Para arrumar, ao invés de chamar `#elapsed()` use `#restart()`:

```
    void PlanejamentoWidget::timeUpdate(){
        QTime t = ui.timeEdit->time();
        ui.timeEdit->setTime(t.addMSecs(time.restart()));
    }
```

O método `#restart()` retorna a quantidade de tempo passada (em milisegundos) desde a última chamada à `#start()` ou `#restart()`.

Veja mais em: [QTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#restart).